# Fortran: Array pointer to different arrays

Tags: pointers, fortran

Is it possible to have a *pointer array to multiple targets*?

Basically I want the following code to work

```fortran
program main

  implicit none

  integer, target  :: a(2), b(3)
  integer, pointer :: ptr(:)

  a = [1, 2]
  b = [3, 4, 5]

  ptr => [a, b]     ! ERROR

  print *, ptr      ! should be 1,2,3,4,5

end program
```

Is it not possible as the targets might not be in in **contiguous** memory?